# ImageButton not changing image

Tags: java, android

I have an image button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/gender_choice"/>
```

the gender_choice.xml is as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/male_gender"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/female_gender"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

For some reason when I run the application and click on the button it doesn't change. Is there something I have to implement in an on click listener?

Comment: because an `ImageButton` does not manage a `checked` state. You need a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using your `drawable` as `background` not `src` and see if it works that way.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:background="@drawable/gender_choice"/>
```

also try changing your drawable and use `state_selected` and `state_pressed` insteead of `state_checked` :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/male_gender" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/male_gender" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/female_gender" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Still nothing, it also seems stretched. Didn't think it would be so difficult to create a icon and make it toggle.

Comment: see my updated answer! I think it'll solve your problem!

Comment: Seems like you're on the right tracks, it goes to the opposite gender for a second then back

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys, so I switched to a ToggleButton, the big issue here is that the background stretched it so it was far too big for the TableRow. Put in a FrameLayout for it though and that solved everything.

So here is my FrameLayout with the ToggleButton which makes a call to gender_choice.xml created in the res/drawable folder.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_column="2">

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gender_choice"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Inside gender_choice.xml is a simple selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/male_gender"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/female_gender"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

That's basically all there was too it, I can't believe I spent like 4 hours on this.